# Specifying custom header styles in BIRT report

Tags: birt

I've been looking into customizing BIRT report styles and came to know the usage of `css` to do this. But the style applies only to a predefined set of BIRT elements. I want know if it's possible to create a report design similar to HTML? 
For example , is it possible create custom header where the shape of the header can be specified by us ? Or maybe change the styling of a table to make it have rounded edges. Is this possible?